# Migrate specific project from TFS 2012 to 2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

We have a collection in TFS 2012 which contains more than one project.
We are considering to migrate to TFS 2013. 
The TFS servers are already up and running.
Is it possible to migrate the data of a specific project in the collection from one TFS server (2012) to the other (2013) or we must migrate the whole collection?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it would be to split up the team project in team project collection and then upgrading only the new team project collection. See below for splitting up team project from project collection

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936158.aspx

Also, the Tfs To Tfs migration guide will be useful.

http://tfstotfsmigration.codeplex.com/releases/view/37382

Comment: Hamid, what you suggest is correct, but Anat should be aware of the consequences. Once you split, you cannot merge back.

Comment: So I won't be able to get all the projects together again in the same collection? I will have to support several collections from now on?

Comment: Your question was about moving a specific project from TFS 2012 to TFS 2013. If you want to move the entire collection, it's the easier option. Just follow the upgrade path for TFS 2013.

What you can't do is to re-merge the separated out project to the project collection.